# Logstash encoder doesnt produce correct json format

Tags: logstash-logback-encoder, loggerfactory

[logback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5437.png)  [jsonfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOKcP.png)

When i produce json logging with loggerfactory it forgets to add commas after each row, any tips? Shall i add something to the logback.xml file?

Comment: `Shall i add something to the logback.xml file?`. Hard to say since you didn't show what you already have inside it

Comment: Added picture, also the jsonFactory part was something i just added i will check if this works

Comment: The jsonFactory did nothing, could it be the filename pattern issue or fieldnames were i should add something

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `LogstashEncoder` is intended to be sent to something that expects line-delimited JSON objects, such as logstash's [`json_lines`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json_lines.html) codec.

Note that adding a comma between JSON objects does not make it valid JSON, since there is no leading `[` or trailing `]` for an array.

Having said that, you can add comma after each object by configuring [a suffix or line separator](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#prefixsuffixseparator)

For example, to add a suffix:

```xml
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
      ...
      <suffix class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
          <pattern>,</pattern>
        </layout>
      </prefix>    
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```